# Getting value of random address location without storing it in a variable

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


struct node{
    int data;
    node* l,*r;
};


int main()
{
    node* n1 = new node;
    cout<<(n1->l);
    return 0;
}
```

in the above code I didn't initialize struct data, l and r. so now the address stored in `n1->l` is `CDCDCDCD`. Now if I want to see the value stored in that address how to see that without storing the address in a variable.

Comment: You are not allowed to dereference an uninitialized pointer, or even read its value for that matter. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: There's nothing stored in that address. `CDCDCDCD` is a special value in MSVC and I'm pretty sure it never maps that page.

Comment: its not clear what you are asking. in you code l and r contain junk becuase you havent put anyhing there. They are random junk pointers. In fact you have seen that the pointer l contains 0xcdcdcdcd , This is what a debug build will typically write to initialized memory so that you can recognize it. What is it that you want to do next?

Comment: That's **undefined behavior**.  Depending on your platform, that could output some arbitrary (not random) address, or garbage (not random) address, or crash (like on a DS9K platform), or some other unexpected behavior.  Personally, I like the crashing behavior the best, but alas that is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Eljay is it UB?, I mean printing the value of an uninitialized pointer? Dereference is UB, but not printing it

Comment: Yes, it is **UB**.  It's uninitialized.  Imagine the DS9K platform that has a bit flag on each word of memory that signifies if it is initialized or not, and if not initialized trying to read that word of memory will fault and abend the program.

Comment: @pm100 Reading _any_ uninitialised variable is UB, regardless of its type.

Comment: Even if your architecture doesn't have trap values, the fact that the standard says this is undefined behavior means the compiler is allowed to assume that code paths hitting undefined behavior are never reached and optimize them out.

Comment: @Eljay TIL thats UB ty

Comment: @Eljay meanwhile back at this question, we have no idea what is being asked :-)

Comment: The title question is "Getting value of random address location without storing it in a variable", but it's not clear what "value of random address location" is intended to mean. If parsed as "value of ((random address) location)", then we see that "the location of a random address" is just the random address itself. And the "value of X" is just "X". So "value of random address location" is just "random address". And you already printed the random address without loading it into variable.

Comment: hey @RaymondChen, sorry for the misinterpretation, I was intended to ask "how to get a value stored in random address without storing that address in variable".

Comment: You can just inline the variable into the expression that dereferences it. `int* p = (int*)0xabcd1234; int value = *p;` becomes `int value = *(int*)0xabcd1234;` after substituting `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you *can* cast any integer to a pointer at your own risk.

```cpp
node* my_ptr = (node*)0xDEADBEEF;  // Casting to a pointer
node my_node = *(node*)0xDEADBEEF; // Casting to a pointer and dereferencing
```

The second line is what I believe you want to do "without storing the address in a variable". However that's hacky and useful only in specific contexts, such as DLL injection.